# how to set content-type for json using XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I am new in Html and javscript, currently I want to send a post request using XmlHttpRequest, the code like following:

```js
export let request = obj => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(obj.method || "GET", obj.url);
        if (obj.headers) {
            Object.keys(obj.headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, obj.headers[key]);
            });
        }

        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);

        xhr.send(obj.body);
    });
};

async function request_create_wl(name, wl) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(wl));
    return request({ url: "/api/cwl", method: 'POST', headers: { 'Conten-Type': 'application/json' }, body: "{a:1}" });
}
```

Which I got a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error.

The response tell me Expected request with `Content-Type: application/json`, and I check the request header, found:

```
Accept:
*/*
...
Conten-Type:application/json
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Obviously, there are 2 content-type headers in request.
I don't know where the 2nd Content-type is from.
I did not set it in code.

Comment: I found the problem..... It is a spell error, I wrote Conten-Type,  missed a 't' in content...